# RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded using default hash method

Tags: python, hash

Why do I get    "  `return self.__hash__()`
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" when I use the default hash method?

```
This causes the error:

def __hash__(self):
    return self.__hash__()

This works:

def __hash__(self):
    return self.name.__hash__()
```

Comment: What do you think `def a(): a()` will do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you are getting into infinite recursion by calling method from itself:

```
def method_name(self):
    return self.method_name()
```

You might wanted to call method of the base class?

```
def __hash__(self):
    return super(ClassName, self).__hash__()
```

Comment: Thanks, it was from a class in a problem set I did, I was pretty sure that was the reason but wanted to verify and you did thanks again.